# Given a list of coordinates, how to join them using a line/curve?

Tags: graphics

I have a list of coordinates (say in 2 dimesnions) inside a bigger list. I plot them using

```
Show[Graphics[{Point[P]}],Graphics[{Red,Point[Q]}]]
```

where P and Q are the respective bigger and smaller coordinate lists. Now I want to highlight a line joining the coordinates in the list Q, I don't want to join all the coordinates pairwise, just successive ones as in a path. Graphics doesn't have a `Joined` option, so how do I do this?

Comment: `Graphics[{Line[Q]}]`?

Comment: Or `Graphics[{Point[P], {Red, Point[Q], Line[Q]}}]`.

Comment: Always start with documentation, if you hit F1 for `Graphics` you should be able to easily find `Line`.

Comment: @Kuba I did go through the documentation for Graphics very briefly, I should have been more thorough. I'm not sure how I can edit it to be more generally relevant though

Comment: @nomaanx If `List` is the answer then you don't need to do anything.

Comment: @Kuba I think you mean `Line` and yes that is the right answer

Answer (score 0):

```
Show[{
   Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Point[{{1, 1}, {2, 1}}]}],
   Graphics[{PointSize[0.02], Red, Point[{{4, 1}, {5, 1}, {6, 1}}]}]
   }] /. {a_, b_} :> {a, b, b /. Point :> Line}
```

[image]

Comment: This is a good candidate to break as soon as an arbitrary pair of whatever stands on its way. Also, if someone is not able to find `Line` then this approach is far from being suited for this skill level.

Comment: @eldo can you please explain what `/. {a_, b_} :> {a, b, b /. Point :> Line}` is doing?